# How to convert RGB image to Luminance image and store the image as .raw file in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, luminance

i am trying to convert an RGB image to a Luminance image and save it as a .raw image to use it in another software. I am using the following code

```
m = imread('20x20-alpha1-1.jpg');
out = zeros(1942,2588);
for i=1:1942
   for j=1:2588
    out(i,j) = 0.2126*m(i,j,1) + 0.7152*m(i,j,2) + 0.0722*m(i,j,3);
   end
end
fileID = fopen('20x20-alpha1-1.raw');
fwrite(fileID,out);
fclose(fileID);
```

However, when I try to open the image with [IrfanViewer](http://www.irfanview.com/), the file is said to be corrupted. Is it a problem in my code ? If so how can I convert this image to Luminance image and save it ?
Thank you :)

Comment: You are simply writing the values with `fopen`. That's not a valid raw picture format. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#File_contents)

Comment: You are writing the raw image data, that's something else then writing a .raw file. The later contains additional information like resolution at the beginning of the file.

Comment: So how is it possible to store one channel image from matlab (Luminance channel) in a .raw file ?

Comment: You'd need to know the specification of the raw format. There's not a single raw format

Comment: @BFMohtedi: What do you really need? To export data in a loseless format, I would use TIFF

Comment: What I need is to have a one channel image (luminance channel) out from an RGB image and that the one channel image is a stand alone file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to mess around with .raw files in this case. Write a tiff file instead:

```
imwrite(out,'20x20-alpha1-1.tiff','tiff')
```

Comment: thank you ! it is much easier like this. However there is one more change to make:
`out(i,j) = uint8(0.2126*m(i,j,1) + 0.7152*m(i,j,2) + 0.0722*m(i,j,3))` to get correct output